# Sticky Footer & ScrollToJS (css on the body is different for both to work)

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollto, sticky-footer

Sticky Footer and ScrollToJS are both great.

**[Sticky Footer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)**
In order to have the sticky footer work correctly you have to have your body element set like:

body { height: 100%; }

---

**[ScrollTo JS](http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)**
In order to have the Scroll To plugin work correctly you have to have your body element set like:

body { height: auto; }

---

The problem is clear... Has anyone implemented both of these together before?

Comment: Please supply us with links to both of the download pages.

Comment: I've updated it with proper links.